# how to make text not pixelate when zooming in sketch

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, sketch-app, anti-aliasing

I'm an illustrator guy who has just moved to sketch.. I noticed that when i type on sketch and zoom in, the text gets pixelated (which is weird considering that it's supposed to be a vector graphic). How do I prevent that and make it behave like illustrator?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should uncheck Show Pixels option in View toolbar
[image]